# Positive and negative parts of a standard normal random variable

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value

I saw this post [correlation between positive and negative part of a Random Variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3430229/correlation-between-positive-and-negative-part-of-a-random-variable) and NCh's answer.

Here $X$ is a standard normal RV, $X^{+}, X^{-}$ are its positive and negative parts.

I find it interesting that $X^- = -\min(X, 0)$ is more commonly used, which would mean that $X^- \geq 0$ and $E[X^-] \geq 0$. What is the reasoning behind this instead of defining $X^ - = \min(X, 0) \leq 0$?

Depending on which definition you use your correlation/covariance will have opposite signs.

In addition, if we use the definition that $X^- = -\min(X, 0) \geq 0$. Then how can $E[X^+ X^-] = 0$? If we use the definition $X^- = \min(X, 0) \leq 0$, then we can make a symmetry argument that its expectation of the product is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter which definition you use so long as the reader is clear.  Similarly with the complex number $2+3i$, you could call the imaginary part $3i$ or $3$ but you need to be clear which you are using.

It may be more convenient in this case to have $X^-$ having the same distribution as $X^+$, which would justify using the non-negative version and $X=X^+ - X^-$

In either definition $X^+ \not=0 \implies X^- =0$ and $X^- \not=0 \implies X^+ =0$ and the product is always $0$

So $\mathbb P(X^+X^-=0)=1$ and $\mathbb E[X^+X^-]=0$

Comment: Makes sense. For a negative $X^-$, is it correct to say that the joint pdf of $X^-, X^+$ is simply the pdf of $X$, i.e., the standard normal pdf? So if you were to take the long route to finding $E[X^+X^-]$, you would integrate 

\begin{align}
    E[X^+X^-] = \int_{-\infty}^0 \int_0^{\infty} x^+ x^- \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{1}{2}(x^{+})^2)  dx^+ dx^- \\
    E[X^+X^-] = \int_{-\infty}^0 x^-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dx^- \\
    = 0
\end{align}

Comment: @Iamanon I would not say that.  Instead perhaps something like  $E[X^+X^-]=\int\limits_{x=-\infty}^0 0 \cdot x \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\tfrac{1}{2}x^2\right) \,dx + \int\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} x \cdot 0 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\tfrac{1}{2}x^2\right) \,dx$

Comment: Ah I see. What would be the joint pdf of $X^+, X^-$ and the marginal pdf of $X^-$ and $X^+$ in this case? It seems a little strange to define them in this case.

Comment: @Iamanon Both $X^+$ and $X^-$ have marginal distributions which are a mixture of discrete and continuous and both are determined by $X$.  So they do not have a joint density.